# Is state changes in React ComponentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

So currently, I am trying to hit API Request `GetAllClients` if state `isAdmin` is `true`. What my code do is, first call an API `GetUserName` to get user `name` and `isAdmin` status. If isAdmin is `true`, call second API request `GetAllClients`. However, for certain reason, the state `isAdmin` still `false` in function `ComponentDidMount`. When I console.log() in `render` function, the state `isAdmin` is `true`.

saveUserName is a function that will assign `name` and `isAdmin` with appropriate `action.payload` using Redux MapDispatchToProps.

I have tried async my ComponentDidMount but still no luck in that.

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const saveUserName = this.props.onSaveUserName;
    const storeClients = this.props.onStoreClients;
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const a = await APIFetchFunctions.GetUserName(localStorage.userId, saveUserName);

    // console.log() isAdmin state here is false 

    if(this.props.isAdmin === true) {
      APIFetchFunctions.GetAllClients(storeClients)
    }
  }

  render() {
    // console.log() isAdmin state here is true
  }
```

I want to get isAdmin to `true` in ComponentDidMount. Not sure if it is possible. If got any other suggestions, you are welcome to suggest here.

Comment: use `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: From where you are passing `isAdmin` prop to this component?

Comment: Assuming that the `isAdmin` value comes from the first api call, does the return value of `const a = await ...` etc. also have access to the `isAdmin` value you're looking for? If so, use the value from there instead of `this.props.isAdmin`. I'm assuming `saveUserName` is something like a redux action that will update the `isAdmin` props in which case it won't be updated until some time in the future and you'll need to do something with `componentDidUpdate` as suggested above.

Comment: it'd be easier for us to help you if you can provide the component code

Comment: Please provide the code from where you are passing `isAdmin`.

Comment: Also, what `const a = await APIFetchFunctions.GetUserName(localStorage.userId, saveUserName);` this line is doing?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I observed two things.

1. After making the `getUsername` api call and getting the result, you are not setting the state of `isAdmin` to true. I think you should to that first.
2. The conditional in componentDidMount shows `this.props.isAdmin` rather than `this.state.isAdmin`. Is this the intended conditional? From what I gathered from the first line of your question, you want to make the second api call if `this.state.isAdmin` is true.